# Facebook : Invalid or no certificate authority found, using bundled information

Tags: php, apache, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login, error-log

Facebook login not working in my PHP Application.I get this error in error log **`Invalid or no certificate authority found, using bundled information`**

I tried to find an answer here, but nothing worked. I enabled the facebook login and created an app on the facebook site.Curl is enabled and I entered the proper facebook id and secret in application configuration file.

**Problem :**

When I click the login button, a facebook console opens and take permission to access my information on facebook. But after I've done that, nothing happens and browser switches between facebook and my application and after few minutes shows that "Two many Redirects".

**`This is what i do so far, please let me know if im doing something wrong, or if i forget something:`**

1. `add` in `base_facebook.php`

   ```
   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false
   ```
2. create a file called **`fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt`** in the facebook-login folder and add content from here:
   https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt

Any immediate help will be highly appreciable. Thanks.